# Как можно объединить эти методы c#?

Tags: c#, методы, рефакторинг

```
public static int Method1(IEnumerable<int> a, int b)
{
    var sum = 0;
    foreach (var x in a)
    {
        sum += b * x;
        b++;
    }
    return sum;
}
        
public static int Method2(IEnumerable<int> a, int b)
{
    var sum = 0;
    foreach (var x in a)
    {
        sum += b * x;
        b = 4 - b;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Может я могу передавать действие которое можно сделать с b? (b = b + 1, b = 4 - b)

```
public static int Method(IEnumerable<int> a, int b, ??? calculation)
{
    var sum = 0;
    foreach (var x in a)
    {
        sum += b * x;
        b = calculation;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно передавать лямбду, для этого используем делегат.

```
public delegate int Operation(int x);

public static int Calculate(IEnumerable<int> a, int b, Operation calculation) {
     var sum = 0;
    foreach (var x in a)
    {
        sum += b * x;
        b = calculation(b);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

делегат определяет сигнатуру лямбды - возвращаемое значение и принимаемые параметры.

Далее, передаём параметром третьим параметром лямбду, которая на каждой итерации цикла выполнит операцию, описанную в вашей лямбда-функции.

Полный пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    public delegate int Operation(int x);

    public static int Calculate(IEnumerable<int> a, int b, Operation calculation) {
         var sum = 0;
        foreach (var x in a)
        {
            sum += b * x;
            b = calculation(b);
        }
        return sum;
    }
        
    static void Main() {
        
        var a = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int b = 1;
        Console.WriteLine(Calculate(a, b, (x) => b * 2));
    }
}
```